# Change base_url pagination CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm coding the pagination from a web, but now I have a problem my pagination give me this url:
www.site.com/published/getClients/5
But I need to change to 
www.site.com/published/getClients/5/2/1
(The first number is the pagination offset).
This is my code:

```
    $limit = 5;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'published/getClients/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('client')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = '3';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

So how can If the last two numbers at last?, something like this($offset is the number 5 from the pagination):

```
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'published/getClients/'.$offset.'/'.$idState.'/'.$idCountry;
```

Please help!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like the below

```
$limit = 5;
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'published/getClients/5/2';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('client')->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = $limit;
$config['uri_segment'] = '5';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Just you have to pass the additional parameters after the function name and then the pagination number and after you have to change the `uri_segment` to 5 since at that position now the page number will come.

Comment: Well I just change the pagination offset to the last segment, thx!